# javascript firebase.auth().signInWifEmailAndPassword not be able to get login in firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working with javascript Firebase in my app.
I'm able to use createUserWithEmailAndPassword successfully in the app. Also, the new user's registration shows inside the Firebase Console.

My question is, how can I check if a user exists or is logged into the browser?

Comment: Do you want to check if a user is logged in? Or do you want to access Firebase Auth with some other application to get a list of users?

Comment: I want to check if a user is logged in or not if logged in go in home page if not logged print massage should registration first \

Answer (score 0):

This code will watch to see if there is a logged in user. It is based on the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) from Firebase. Let me know if you need to know about the flow and authentication tokens etc.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
    console.log('There is a user') 
    } else {
    console.log('Nobody is home: Need to login or sign up!');
    }
    });
```